# Scheduling a coroutine inside a non-coroutine method

Tags: python, async-await

I'm maintaining a project where I have the case that I need to schedule a
coroutine inside a synchronous function that is already running inside the event loop.

My problem boils down to this:

```py
import asyncio

class SomeScheduler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.workers = []

    # This is not a coroutine yet
    def close(self):
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.close()

    def register_worker(self, worker):
        self.workers.append(worker)

    async def run(self):
        for _ in range(3):
            print("Doing stuff")
            coros = map(lambda x: x.work(), self.workers)
            await asyncio.gather(*coros)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)


class SomeWorkerA:
    def close(self):
        print("Closing WorkerA")

    async def work(self):
        print("Working WorkerA")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        print("Done WorkerA")

class SomeWorkerB:
    def close(self):
        print("Closing WorkerB")

    async def work(self):
        print("Working WorkerB")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.4)
        print("Done WorkerB")

async def main():
    sched = SomeScheduler()
    sched.register_worker(SomeWorkerA())
    sched.register_worker(SomeWorkerB())

    try:
        await sched.run()
    finally:
        sched.close()
        print("Bye")


asyncio.run(main())
```

For historic reasons, `SomeScheduler.close()` is not a coroutine and I cannot
change the API (without having a huge discussion in the team).

Now I have a new type of worker:

```py
class SomeWorkerC:
    async def close(self):
        print("Closing WorkerC")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        print("Done closing WorkerC")

    async def work(self):
        print("Working WorkerC")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.4)
        print("Done WorkerC")
```

If I add `sched.register_worker(SomeWorkerC())` in the `main()` function, then
the problem is that the `SomeWorkerC.close()` does not get executed, I get this
error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'SomeWorkerC.close' was never awaited
  co = None
```

That makes sense, so I though of changing the `SomeScheduler.close()` like this:

```py
class SomeScheduler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.workers = []

    def close(self):
        for worker in self.workers:
            co = worker.close()
            if isinstance(co, types.CoroutineType):
                loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
                loop.create_task(co)
```

which only works partially correct, the `stdout` output is:

```
...
Done WorkerA
Done WorkerB
Done WorkerC
Closing WorkerA
Closing WorkerB
Bye
Closing WorkerC
```

but I also expected that `print("Done closing WorkerC")` gets executed, however
this is not the case as you can see from the `stdout` output. The documentation
of [`loop.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) says:

> Schedule the execution of a Coroutines. Return a Task object.

so I assumed that the whole task would be executed but it seems that only until the
first `await` was executed, the rest of the task was not executed. I cannot do
`loop.run_forever()` or `loop.run_until_complete(co)` because the loop is still
running.

I even tried to replace the loop with another loop:

```py
class SomeScheduler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.workers = []

    def close(self):
        for worker in self.workers:
            co = worker.close()

            if isinstance(co, types.CoroutineType):
                current_loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
                loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
                asyncio.run(co)
```

but this fails with `RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running
event loop` and if I do `asyncio.gather(co)` instead, then the first part gets
executed but then this is raised:

```
...
Closing WorkerA
Closing WorkerB
Bye
Closing WorkerC
_GatheringFuture exception was never retrieved
future: <_GatheringFuture finished exception=CancelledError()>
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

At this point I'm not even sure whether I can solve this without changing the
API and making `SomeScheduler.close()` a co-routine. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because the async code in the worker's `.close` coroutine would never be run in the running event loop because it is currently being blocked by `SomeScheduler`'s synchronous `.close`; i.e. the async worker would not be closed until the scheduler's `.close` has stopped blocking the event loop, which clearly isn't possible because the worker's close is downstream of the scheduler's close.

The way to solve this is to call an async close upstream of the scheduler's `.close`; e.g.

```py
def shutdown():
    await scheduler.async_close()  # close async workers
    scheduler.close()  # close sync workers
```